# heroku app asks for sign in without me enabling it

Tags: spring, rest, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am making a spring application deployed on Heroku. However when I go to the url (.herokuapp.com) I get asked to provide my username and password, even when I didnt put that in my code anywhere. I tried to add the following to my code:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
        security
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable();
    }
```

however when I make a request using postman I now get a 403 forbidden error.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have added Spring security in your project and as soon as you include spring security in your application it automatically protects your whole application, so in order to access the pages without login you need to configure it, `you can use AntMatcher("/endpoint").permitAll();`
something like this to configure it and the default username is user and password is generated at the start of the application.

You should probably go through the basics of spring security in order to understand it properly. Follow this video [spring security](https://youtu.be/fjkelzWNSuA) to get ht e insight.